# Azure REST API - query parameters for getting all the virtual machine

Tags: rest, azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to query all the virtual Machines in a subscription, but I want to be able to filter using a query param and not by code.

I am able to get all the virtual machines but I want to know if I can filter them and how.

I am not using the classic REST but ARM.

Comment: Are you using the classic VMs or Azure Resource Manager ?

Comment: I am using Azure Resource Manager

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is the API you use:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resources?&api-version={api-version}
```

then you can use filter like this:

```
?$filter={filter}
```

Your request will look like this:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resources?$filter=name eq {resourcename}&api-version={api-version}
```

`$filter` is optional and is used to filter results. Replace {filter} with one of the following values:

```
$filter=tagname eq {value}
$filter=tagname eq {tagname} and tagvalue eq {tagvalue}
$filter=startswith(tagname, {tagname prefix})
$filter=resourceType eq {resourceProviderNamespace/resourceType}
$filter=name eq {resourcename}
$filter=location eq {locationname}
```

Currently, you **cannot** use the **tagname** or **tagvalue** filters with other filters; such as, **name**, **location**, or **resourceType**.

To get all the Resources of type VM you can use a filter like this:

```
$filter=resourceType eq {Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines}
```

For more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790569.aspx

Comment: I tried all of those and it just give me invalid filter :(

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno what's the api version you use?

Comment: version 2014-04-01

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno I think those are old APIs, Try using 1.5 or 1.6 instead.

Comment: How to adjust this call to pull all the machines fora certain subscription ?

Comment: How can I add multiple filters. 
I want do do something like this. It doesn't work

(tagName eq 'Name1' and tagValue eq 'Value1') 
and 
(tagName eq 'Name2' and tagValue eq 'Value2')

Answer (score 3):

I would add one change on @Aram's answer.
An example for a filter would have to include single quotes, like:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resources?$filter=name eq 'some_name'&api-version={api-version}
```

So possible filters would be:

```
$filter=tagname eq 'value'
$filter=tagname eq 'tagname' and tagvalue eq 'tagvalue'
$filter=resourceType eq 'resourceProviderNamespace/resourceType'
```

Comment: It helps but, how can i add a resource group filter ?