# Azure REST API location filter

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to GET filtered responses from Azure RM using the REST API . The Type filter is working , But When I try to get with Location filter , it always imposes as a wrong query filter .

For example , I need to get Virtual Networks from Location 'ukwest' I am giving the following REST API link , it never works .

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription_ID/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualnetworks?$filter=location%20eq%20'ukwest'&api-version=2017-06-01

But according to this type filter works , 
[Azure REST API - query parameters for getting all the virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270735/azure-rest-api-query-parameters-for-getting-all-the-virtual-machine)

I did not find any document Related to this in Azure , It would be nice if I get some spark here.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to filter by location? Please update your question to include that information.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am getting the query filter "location eq 'ukwest'" is an invalid filter query string .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the REST API documentation for listing all Virtual Networks in an Azure Subscription [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network/virtualnetwork/list-virtual-networks-within-a-subscription), I believe that `$filter` criteria is not supported.

What you would need to do is use `Resource Manager API` to get all resources and filter that by resource type and location (as mentioned in the answer you linked). So your request URL would be:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resources?$filter=resourceType%20eq%20'Microsoft.Network/virtualnetworks'%20and%20location eq%20'ukwest'&api-version={api-version}
```

Do give it a try.

Comment: Thanks it works ! Where can I get the list of resource types which I am going to give it in URI ? like resource groups , Availability sets, security groups etc.

Comment: Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers#Providers_List. HTH.

Comment: Thanks dude ! you saved my time.