# How to filter Azure Resource Management REST call on tags

Tags: rest, azure

I would like to get a list of resources in Azure containing a given tag.
The basic request form is as follows:
`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources`

I can append `$filter` parameter, however using `tags` generates an error, which is likely due to `tags` being a dictionary.

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidFilterInQueryString","message":"Invalid $filter 'tags eq '{}'' specified in the query string."}}
```

[Documentation for filter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/filter-syntax) does not mention how to filter on lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a tag pair name:value=abc:123, you can append `$filter=tagname eq 'abc' and tagvalue eq '123'` parameter.

I test this from this [Resources - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) just via clicking **Try it**. Add the $filter parameter with values including single quotes.

[image]

The response with filtered resources.
[image]

The full example will be like this:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resources?$filter=name eq 'some_name'&api-version={api-version}
```

You can get more details from this [Azure REST API - query parameters for getting all the virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270735/azure-rest-api-query-parameters-for-getting-all-the-virtual-machine).

Comment: I did notice however that including $filter for tagname has the adverse effect of removing the tags node from the API response. It looks like a poor design choice, or a bug. Did you noitece the same?

Comment: Yes, I notice that the result is indeed returning the filtered resources with a given tag not including "tag". It looks like a bug, I have created a [new issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/657) on Github, you can notice that. Hope this can helps.

Comment: I am trying to add multiple filters but it doesnt work

(tagName eq 'Name1' and tagValue eq 'Value1') 
and 
(tagName eq 'Name2' and tagValue eq 'Value2')

Did you ever have to do something like this?

Comment: Sorry, I have not to do so. If you find something, good to share it.